# Get file name / path of open file in Excel

Tags: java, excel

Been searching around for ages for this but with no avail.

Is there a way (using Java) to get the file name / path of all files open in Excel?

Comment: in a certain directory ?

Comment: Could do, looking for either.  We would know the directory of the files though.

Comment: check this Might help   http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-get-all-files-with-certain-extensions-in-a-directory-including-subdirectories.html